# how to process compressed (tar file) in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a tarfile in amazon s3 named "myarchive_1.tar.gz" which i want to extract in amazon s3 itself through AWS Glue.

This is my sample code which i am running in AWS Glue.

```
**Sample Code:-**
 #Extracting tar file contents
 tar = tarfile.open("s3://dsb-lfnsrn-001/lndg/archive/myarchive_1.tar.gz")
 tar.extractall("s3://dsb-lfnsrn-001/pckpby/archive")
 tar.close()
```

But whenever i am running it in aws glue getting the following error

```
**Error Code:-**
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://dsb-lfnsrn-
  001/lndg/archive/myarchive_1.tar.gz'
  End of LogType:stdout
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Yogita.

Comment: First of all you should read data from `glueContext` object not `tailFile`. Second - have you configure AIM policy for glue? It looks like your glue job simple does not have correct right to s3. Could you please post your policy (may be obfuscated) and job code?